# Design pattern for using my own reusable components/services across different applications?

Tags: angular, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

Do you know/recommend any design patterns/best practices to export my own reusable components (eg. a login form) or services (e.g. authentication service) and import/inject them across different Angular applications?

Comment: Do you mean libraries?

Comment: Yes, i guess that's the right term. So it's about sharing my own libraries across multiple angular applications.

Comment: I would look into how to create an npm package. Add your individual components to the package, and import the package to a project where you want to use it. Though your components then need to be universal enough so they would fit anywhere (a hard task I might say).

Comment: The universal thing you're addressing is probably the hardest challenge. But I'm sure there exist some design patterns/best practices for that matter..

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own library and install it through npm.

[As Angular docs says:](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)

> If you find that you need to solve the same problem in more than one
> application (or want to share your solution with other developers),
> you have a candidate for a library. A simple example might be a button
> that sends users to your company website, that would be included in
> all applications that your company builds.

Answer (score 0):

This is more for the discussion, but I'd say it would be best to lay down exactly what ypu want with the package first.

Are you going to make it just to use in your own projects, without much consideration for wider use and if other people would be able to use it easily? Then you can start by creating it in your regular project surroundings with all the other components.

If, however, you plan on making it useful for others too, you might first check what's available on npm atm and see what would make your new package different or more convenient.

Now, regardless of your plans, I'd suggest making the package component or service as dumb as you can, taking the inputs that are necessary to make it work and adding specific logic only for what it's intended to do, eventually returning or outputing as few data as possible. If you see that the package is getting bigger and with more complicated logic, it might be better to break it into more packages.

When it comes to UI and styling - and this depends on your choice of answers to questions above, much more than the logic depends on them - in the first case I'd go with styles closest to my preferred ones, but not 100% percent (I'd leave colours for specific use and put if component's files, not hardcoded) and in the second case I'd try to make it as much user-definable as I can, in the way of making the component main styles dependant on global css styles that the user can edit.

Finally, whatever you end up with, I'd *heavily* comment it in the readme file, because there's nothing more frustrating than finding a package that claims to do what you need, only to find out you have to spend more time in figuring out how to tweak it, than actually coding it all from  the scratch.